# How to deal with abstract function problems

Tags: functions, expression-test

Suppose that the function $f(x)$ has a second derivative, and $g(x)=f(0)(1-x)+f(1) x$, then which statement on [0,1] is correct?

$$\begin{array}{c}
&(A)& \text{When} \;  f^{\prime}(x) \geq 0  ,  f(x) \geq g(x) 
&(B)& \text{When} \;  f^{\prime}(x) \geq 0  ,  f(x) \leq g(x) \\
&(C)&  \text{When} \; f^{\prime \prime}(x) \leq 0  ,  f(x) \geq g(x) 
&(D)& \text{When} \;  f^{\prime \prime}(x) \leq 0  ,  f(x) \leq g(x) 
\end{array}$$

The correct answer is `C`, but when I want to verify this conclusion with MMA, the following code cannot output the verification result:

```
g[x_] := f[0] (1 - x) + f[1] x
Resolve[ForAll[x, 0 < x < 1 && f''[x] <= 0, f[x] < g[x]], Reals]
```

I want to know what method can be used to deal with this abstract function problem.

**Remarks:** When assigning a specific function to $f(x)$, the following code can output the verification result, but I want to deal with this abstract function directly.

```
f[x_] := x^3
g[x_] := f[0] (1 - x) + f[1] x
Resolve[ForAll[x, 0 < x < 1, f[x] < g[x]], Reals]
```